# ¿Cómo imprimir los atributos de cada objeto de una lista, en Python?

Tags: python

tengo un diccionario definido de esta forma:

```
movements = {
    "KYOGRE": {
        1: {
            "name": "HYDRO PUMP",
            "type": "WATER",
            "pp": 5,
            "category": "special", 
            "power": 110, 
            "accuracy": 80,
            "secundary_effect": "",
            "possibility": ""
        },
        2: {
            "name": "SURF",
            "type": "WATER",
            "pp": 15,
            "category": "special", 
            "power": 90, 
            "accuracy": 100,
            "secundary_effect": "",
            "possibility": ""
        }, 
        3: {
            "name": "WATERFALL",
            "type": "WATER",
            "pp": 15,
            "category": "physic", 
            "power": "80", 
            "accuracy": "100",
            "secundary_effect": "FLINCH",
            "possibility": 20
        },
        4: {
            "name": "THUNDER",
            "type": "ELECTRIC",
            "pp": 10,
            "category": "special", 
            "power": "110", 
            "accuracy": "70",
            "secundary_effect": "PARALYZE",
            "possibility": 30
        }
    }
}

return movements[str(pokemon).upper()].values()
```

al enviar kyogre me duelve una lista con esta estructura:

```
[dict_values([
{'name': 'HYDRO PUMP', 'type': 'WATER', 'pp': 5, 'category': 'special', 'power': 110, 'accuracy': 80, 'secundary_effect': '', 'possibility': ''}, 

{'name': 'SURF', 'type': 'WATER', 'pp': 15, 'category': 'special', 'power': 90, 'accuracy': 100, 'secundary_effect': '', 'possibility': ''}, 

{'name': 'WATERFALL', 'type': 'WATER', 'pp': 15, 'category': 'physic', 'power': '80', 'accuracy': '100', 'secundary_effect': 'FLINCH', 'possibility': 20}, 

{'name': 'THUNDER', 'type': 'ELECTRIC', 'pp': 10, 'category': 'special', 'power': '110', 'accuracy': '70', 'secundary_effect': 'PARALYZE', 'possibility': 30}])
]
```

imprimiendolos de esta manera:

```
def run(self):
    for attacks in range(len(self.pokemon_movements)):
        print(self.pokemon_movements[attacks].name)
```

el output deberia de ser:

```
hydro pump
surf
dive
thunder
```

me da el error: `'dict_values' object has no attribute 'name'`

Comment: Para entender mejor el problema, ¿cual es resultado que esperas obtener? Edita tu pregunta y escribe una muestra de la salida deseada para el pokemon en cuestión. Probablemente te saltaste un paso.

Comment: @CandidMoe listo, el resultado que quiero es dependiendo del atributo imprimirlo

Comment: Es importante incluir el resultado esperado, pues asi puedo validar que mi respuesta sea correcta.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

El problema está en esta linea,

```
return movements[str(pokemon).upper()].values()
```

que retorna un objeto del tipo <class 'dict_values'>, con el siguiente contenido:

```
dict_values([{'name': 'HYDRO PUMP', 'type': 'WATER', 'pp': 5, 'category': 'special', 'power': 110, 'accuracy': 80, 'secundary_effect': '', 'possibility': ''}, {'name': 'SURF', 'type': 'WATER', 'pp': 15, 'category': 'special', 'power': 90, 'accuracy': 100, 'secundary_effect': '', 'possibility': ''}, {'name': 'WATERFALL', 'type': 'WATER', 'pp': 15, 'category': 'physic', 'power': '80', 'accuracy': '100', 'secundary_effect': 'FLINCH', 'possibility': 20}, {'name': 'THUNDER', 'type': 'ELECTRIC', 'pp': 10, 'category': 'special', 'power': '110', 'accuracy': '70', 'secundary_effect': 'PARALYZE', 'possibility': 30}])
```

Lo que necesitas en cambio es directamente el diccionario del pokemon correspondiente (no `dict_values`), que se obtiene así:

```
resultado = movements[str(pokemon).upper()]
```

que resulta en un diccionario indexado por número de ataque:

```
{1: {'name': 'HYDRO PUMP', 'type': 'WATER', 'pp': 5, 'category': 'special', 'power': 110, 'accuracy': 80, 'secundary_effect': '', 'possibility': ''}, 2: {'name': 'SURF', 'type': 'WATER', 'pp': 15, 'category': 'special', 'power': 90, 'accuracy': 100, 'secundary_effect': '', 'possibility': ''}, 3: {'name': 'WATERFALL', 'type': 'WATER', 'pp': 15, 'category': 'physic', 'power': '80', 'accuracy': '100', 'secundary_effect': 'FLINCH', 'possibility': 20}, 4: {'name': 'THUNDER', 'type': 'ELECTRIC', 'pp': 10, 'category': 'special', 'power': '110', 'accuracy': '70', 'secundary_effect': 'PARALYZE', 'possibility': 30}}
```

Usando el patrón común `for k, v in resultado.items():` puedo recorrer este diccionario obteniendo en cada iteración el número de ataque (en `k`) y el diccionario con su valores (en `v`):

```
for numero, ataque in resultado.items():
    ataque = ataque['name']
    print(numero, ataque)
```

#### Demo

```
movements = {
    "KYOGRE": {
        1: {
            "name": "HYDRO PUMP",
            "type": "WATER",
            "pp": 5,
            "category": "special",
            "power": 110,
            "accuracy": 80,
            "secundary_effect": "",
            "possibility": ""
        },
        2: {
            "name": "SURF",
            "type": "WATER",
            "pp": 15,
            "category": "special",
            "power": 90,
            "accuracy": 100,
            "secundary_effect": "",
            "possibility": ""
        },
        3: {
            "name": "WATERFALL",
            "type": "WATER",
            "pp": 15,
            "category": "physic",
            "power": "80",
            "accuracy": "100",
            "secundary_effect": "FLINCH",
            "possibility": 20
        },
        4: {
            "name": "THUNDER",
            "type": "ELECTRIC",
            "pp": 10,
            "category": "special",
            "power": "110",
            "accuracy": "70",
            "secundary_effect": "PARALYZE",
            "possibility": 30
        }
    }
}

pokemon = "KYOGRE"
resultado = movements[str(pokemon).upper()]

print(pokemon)
print("Ataques:")
for numero, ataque in resultado.items():
    ataque = ataque['name']
    print(numero, ataque)
```

produce

```
KYOGRE
Ataques:
1 HYDRO PUMP
2 SURF
3 WATERFALL
4 THUNDER

Process finished with exit code 0
```

Comment: a mi me lo devuelve como un array: ```[{1: {'name': 'HYDRO PUMP', 'type': 'WATER'...}]```

Comment: @plus. Mi código está completo, probado y comprobado. Tomalo como guía para implementarlo correctamente en tu app.